# How common is quantum symmetry?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, gauge-theory

It is well-known that, if I have a two-dimensional quantum field theory, $\mathcal{Q}$, with a *finite, abelian,* non-anomalous global symmetry $\Gamma$, and I gauge it, the resulting theory (which I denote $\mathcal{Q}/\!\!/\Gamma$) has the Pontryagin dual group, $\widehat{\Gamma}:=\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma,\mathrm{U}(1))$, as a global symmetry. This is known as quantum symmetry or Ponryagin dual symmetry.

Relatively recently it was understood that the story is quite a bit more general. In $d$ dimensions with a $p$-form symmetry, the dual symmetry is a $(d-p-2)$-form symmetry, while if $\Gamma$ is finite but non-abelian, the Pontryagin dual symmetry is a non-invertible symmetry, usually denoted as $\mathrm{Rep}(\Gamma)$ or variations thereof depending on the dimensionality and/or other data that specify the symmetry category.

My question is, *how common is it*, actually, in a generic gauge theory?

For that, let's imagine the following scenario. I have a pure $G$-gauge theory where $G$ is any group (I could specialise to a subcategory of groups, such as connected or simply connected, if technically necessary, but I think it's fine as is). I want to think about it as starting off with the trivial theory with $G$-symmetry and gauging $G$, so I'll denote it $\bullet/\!\!/G$. In this type of gauge theories, there isn't necessarily Pontryagin dual symmetry for all of $G$ because the gauging involves summing over non-flat bundles (for the continuous pieces of $G$) and hence it is not an invertible process -- which Pontryagin duality (or more generally Tannaka-Krein duality and generalisations) would imply. However what I could do, starting with the trivial $G$-symmetric theory, $\bullet$, is choose any finite (probably need *normal*) subgroup $\Gamma\subset G$ and gauge $G/\Gamma$ to get $\bullet/\!\!/(G/\Gamma)$, which still has global symmetry $\Gamma$, since I didn't gauge it. Then gauge $\Gamma$, to get $\left[\bullet/\!\!/(G/\Gamma)\right]/\!\!/\Gamma \cong \bullet/\!\!/G$. Since in the last step I only gauged a finite group, I expect to get back a Pontryagin dual global symmetry, $\widehat{\Gamma}=\mathrm{Rep}(\Gamma)$.

The above argument implies the following:

> Any pure $G$-gauge theory has a $(d-2)$-form Pontryagin dual global symmetry
> $\widehat{\Gamma}_\text{max}=\mathrm{Rep}(\Gamma_\text{max})$, where
> $\Gamma_\text{max}$ is the maximal (normal?) finite subgroup of $G$.

Is this true? It seems a bit too strong to be true. If not, what is wrong with the argument?

Moreover, in a simple example, this is not how it seems to work. Let's take $G=\mathrm{SU}(2)$ and $\Gamma= Z(\mathrm{SU}(2))\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$. Then $G/\Gamma\cong \mathrm{SO}(3)$ and $\bullet/\!\!/(G/\Gamma)$ is the pure $\mathrm{SO}(3)$-gauge theory. To go to the $\mathrm{SU}(2)$-gauge theory one gauges the centre $\mathbb{Z}_2$ as a *one-form* symmetry! Which would result in a $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}_2$ dual symmetry that is a $(d-3)$-form symmetry, instead of a $(d-2)$-form symmetry as the above argument would suggest. Or could one gauge $\mathbb{Z}_2$ either as a zero-form symmetry (which acts on nothing in $\bullet/\!\!/\mathrm{SO}(3)$), or as a one-form symmetry and obtain different quantum symmetries in either case?

Comment: You are assuming that gauging $G/\Gamma$ would preserve $\Gamma$. This is generally not true.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was the dodgy point. But in this setup (where the starting theory is the trivial theory) what happens to $\Gamma$? Said differently what conditions must the theory, $G$, and $\Gamma$ obey so that this *is* true?

Comment: I'll write an answer and you can see whether it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

In the following I assume that the $G$ symmetry is faithful.

I think the caveat is the step of gauging $G/\Gamma$, which is not necessarily normal.

Start from a theory with global symmetry $G$, and suppose $\Gamma$ is a non-anomalous normal subgroup. Just to make things simple, let's assume $G$ is 0-form. Then what we know for sure is that we can definitely gauge $\Gamma$ and the resulting theory has $G/\Gamma$ symmetry. You can further gauge $G/\Gamma$ to gauge the full symmetry $G$.

Now, suppose you want to gauge $G/\Gamma$ first instead. Let us again assume that there is no anomaly. The problem now is that $G/\Gamma$ is generally not normal. But we do not need this conclusion.) There are two things that can happen:

1. Gauging $G/\Gamma$ breaks $\Gamma$. A simple example is $G=S_3=Z_3\rtimes Z_2$. Take $\Gamma=Z_3$ (which is normal). Gauging $G/\Gamma=Z_2$ breaks $\Gamma$.
2. You can not gauge $G/\Gamma$ without also gauging (full or part of) $\Gamma$. This happens for example when $G$ is a nontrivial central extension of $G/\Gamma$ by $\Gamma$, and is exactly the case of your $G=SU(2), \Gamma=Z_2$ example.

Edit: the comment pointed out that the case 1 might be more subtle according to footnote 1 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.09542. In 2d, the resulting theory has a non-invertible symmetry.

Edit: In case 2, here is a heuristic argument for the SU(2) example: since the symmetry group is $SU(2)$, SU(2) must act faithfully, so there exist operators that transform under all irreps of SU(2). In that case, when SO(3) is gauged, the $Z_2$ part, which is $2\pi$ rotation in SO(3), must be gauged as well for consistency. In fact, we do not need the faithfullness assumption here. The faithfullness just guarantees that the $Z_2$ acts nontrivially, but we do not need it for the argument.

Your argument works when $G=\Gamma \times G/\Gamma$. It seems that one of the above must happen if it is not a direct product.

Comment: Aha, I think $G/\Gamma$ being non-normal is indeed the culprit, thanks! However, I don't fully understand either of the points. I think point 1. is a bit too rough, you don't really lose $\Gamma$ (see footnote 1 in this paper of Tachikawa https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.09542). For point 2. can you explain why gauging $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ gauges $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in this case?

Comment: I don't understand Tachikawa's footnote 1, so I'll leave point 1 as is (and examples I know in higher dimensions support my conclusion). But at least in that case gauging $G/\Gamma$ the theory does not have $\Gamma$ symmetry. I'll add more to my point 2.

Comment: Could you maybe give references for the higher-d non-normal examples you have in mind? I'd like to understand the clash between these and Tachikawa's footnote.

Comment: I disagree with the explanation for point 2. By definition in the theory $\bullet$, $G$ does not act faithfully, since $\bullet$ is the trivial theory. What you say is, I guess, true in a $G$-gauge theory that is not pure gauge.

Comment: Well, if $G$ does not act faithfully, then it is not the $G$ symmetry to begin with. I think we might have a different understanding of what a trivial theory means. This whole discussion does not need to assume anything about dynamics or whether it's trivial or not.

Comment: My statement that gauging $G/\Gamma$ breaks $\Gamma$ does not necessarily contradict Tachikawa's footnote. It says in 2d there is a new non-invertible symmetry after gauging $G/\Gamma$ (when it's semi-direct product).

Comment: By trivial theory, I meant the theory whose full spectrum on any manifold is just the identity operator. This theory trivially has symmetry $G$ (not acting on anything) (it also has any other symmetry you wish). Gauging $G$ gives precisely pure $G$-gauge theory.

Comment: As for the non-normal references, I just want to understand better the story of gauging a non-normal subgroup. I understand that it may not contradict your statement. In fact, I hope it doesn't, because this is the most probable resolution of my confusion.

Comment: OK, you can work with the trivial theory. I'll modify my answer so that it applies only to theories where $G$ acts faithfully.